# How to add float and non-float, others?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How can I add all the `mybag` array values into `total_w` where `mybag` has mixed values of `float` or `int`?

```
  var mybag = []; 
  mybag[0] = 20.50; 
  mybag[1] = 10.13;
  mybag[3] = 0;

  //so total_w should be 30.63  not: 20.5010.13

  var total_w = 0;
  var comma = '';
  for (key in mybag) {
    active_mybag = active_mybag + comma + parseFloat(mybag[key]).toFixed(2);
    total_w = Math.round(total_w + parseFloat(mybag[key]).toFixed(2));
    comma = ",";    
  }

  console.log('> ', total_w, active_mybag);
```

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string

Comment: why are you calling `toFixed`? that converts it toa string.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but [don't use `for..in` to loop an array.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/5743988)

Comment: i need to use toFixed because sometimes the mybag is with value like 20.345677 or 5.02929292

Comment: then you have to convert it back to a number. should be `parseFloat(mybag[key].toFixed(2))`, and as 4castle said don't use for...in on arrays.

Comment: What happened to `mybag[2]`?

Comment: delete mybag[2]; happens sometime.

Comment: i used without toFixed(2); but then i get a value still as 20.5010.13 instead of adding

Comment: You are not dealing with numbers but with strings then.

Comment: Correct, its all mixed up in the array. STRING, FLOAT, INT all together is there.

Comment: So? Why do you mix different data types? If you want to add numbers - make sure they are all numbers. Otherwise it's - Garbage In Garbage Out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var active_mybag = [];  

  var total_w = mybag.reduce(function(acc,e){

    // Value of array to float
    e = parseFloat(e);

    // Collect text representations of rounded value
    active_mybag.push( e.toFixed(2) );

    // Subtotal
    return acc + e;

  },0 ).toFixed(2); // Convert sum to string representation

  active_mybag = active_mybag.join(',');
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/ot1p37mv/ ]

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code, so rather than a string of comments here's an answer.

```
var mybag = [ /* bunch of values */];
var total = +mybag.reduce((a, b) => a + +b, 0).toFixed(2);
```

Will work with numbers or numeric strings. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cke2swmt/). Here's a break down:

the reduce starts with 0.

the 'a' parameter is the accumulator.

the 'b' parameter is the array value for that iteration.

b is converted to a number by the unary plus operator

b is added to a and returned

the total sum is reduced to a numeric string of 2-digit precision

which is converted back to a number by the plus at the front

Comment: That's great, but the comments are necessary for them to actually learn anything.

Comment: It's not a "coercion" but "conversion"

Comment: @4castle was in the process of writing the explanation :)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/16502176/ - this is also working. I am not getting your second line, can you show with a working example as per question.

Comment: I wasn't talking about explaining *your* code, I meant you need to explain what was wrong with *their* code so that they can solve their future questions too.

Comment: @YumYumYum no, my code works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/cke2swmt/ all I changed was translating the es6 arrow function to the regular function syntax.